# Is it possible to create a destination folder after selecting files to be moved

Tags: command-line, files, mv

I am facing a specific problem where I have to manually deal with multiple files from different directories. I will like to know if it is possible to create a destination a destination folder on the fly for the already selected files.

Comment: "Selected"? Could you pease give an example of what you have and what it is you'd like to achieve?

Comment: Basically I want to move files from multiple directories to one directory, but I want to create the destination directory on the same command as the ```mv ``` command; an example: ```mv **/*.zip``` and ```Here i want to create the destination directory```

Comment: No, directory has to exist first, then you can move the files. You can always combine commands on one line, as in `mkdir somedir; mv **/*.zip somedir/`  and there's a way to make it shorter to not repeat the directory name.

Comment: Well, you can switch to a different terminal window (or screen window, etc.) and run `mkdir` ... Or you could write a script to do this..

Answer (score 0):

A script to do this is is [less simple than you'd think in POSIX shell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1853946/getting-the-last-argument-passed-to-a-shell-script), but is easy in bash:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

mkdir -p "${@: -1}" || exit 1
mv "$@"
```

That uses a Bash-ism to get the last argument and `mkdir` it. The `-p` option to mkdir makes the entire chain of directories, so if you try to create "dir/subdir" it'll work.

Answer (score 0):

Possible duplicate of [Is there a way to make mv create the directory to be moved to if it doesn't exist?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/547927/2519977).

You can use a bash script and an alias to make a "new command" for that.

`cmv.sh`

```
#!/bin/bash

mkdir --parents "$2"; mv "$1" "$_"
```

And in `~/.bashrc` add the line:

```
alias cmv="/path/to/cmv.sh"
```

And then you can use it like:

```
~# cmv **/*.zip destination
```

And the destination will be created.